# How to change permissions for files in .git

Tags: linux, git, unix, github, file-permissions

We have a one local branch called develop. All testing will be done on develop branch. All developers will pull their changes into develop branch from their respective branches with common user access to server.Everything working fine.

Now all users got their individual access to server. When developers are pulling changes from respective branches to develop branch. We are facing .git/index.lock issue. I think this is because of each user is pulling with their own user in server. If we change .git/index permisson to 777 will it work? Or any better solution for this.

Comment: Is the server or client who face the index.lock issue? It doesn't seem that server can encounter the problem.

Comment: Its the server. In our team we will develop directly in server in our own branches.

Comment: So what's the reason for developing in server? Since Git is a powerful distributed versioning system, you can develop individually on your PCs and everything will works fine.

Comment: Yes we can do that. But it was configured directly in server.

Comment: So that breaks the Git principles, and the problem can't be resolved even you change the file permission.

Comment: By changing .git folder permission to 777 the index file issue got resolved